# what does `<<` syntax means in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know this is silly but anyways I came across this code here in SO.

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
   total += someArray[i] << 0;
}
```

This is getting the sum of array's values. But i do not understand the last line.

```
total += someArray[i] << 0;
               //-----^^--here
```

What `<<` means ? am i missing something all this while. and yes!! why `<<`.

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1828469/1586880

Comment: Bitwise left shift: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: Guys, I suppose the answer should explain **why** `<< 0`

Comment: @zerkms I agree, but the OP doesn't seem to ask that, even though that definitely seems to be the concern

Comment: @user2246674 I never said they shouldn't :) I agree with that 100%! I was just pointing out what the OP literally said

Comment: What are the contents of `someArray`? It either is used to cast numbers to 32-bit integers, or oddly to convert strings to numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The next question would be "why << 0"?

*All* [bitwise / bitshift operators](http://es5.github.io/#x11.7) in JavaScript invoke [`[ToInt32]`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.5) on both arguments.

Thus, `x << 0` (as in this case), `x | 0`, and `~~x` have the effect of *coercing the value to an integer* within [0, 2^32).

Compare this to `+x` which merely coerces x into a number.

Comment: One more for the list: `~~x`, i.e. [double bitwise NOT](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/). Also note that, unlike `Math.floor`, these bitwise tricks always round *towards zero*.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Thanks for the good addition.

Comment: yup!! thanks (for the links too)..:)

Answer (score 5):

`<<` and `>>` are bitshift operations, taking an integer number and shifting all the bits left (`<<`) or right (`>>`) by 1 bit. If followed by another number, the shift happens for that many bits, so `256 << 4` shifts the bitpatter for `256` left by 4 bits (filling the bit patter from the right with four zeros).

Most programming languages support these operators, and you usually have no reason to use them unless you're writing code that has to act on bit patterns for (usually super-fast) integer operations.

As a nice quirk in JavaScript, if you apply bitwise operations to a number, it gets forced to an integer, so shifting by 0 bits, or taking the or operation with 0, `... | 0` will turn "a number" into an 32 bit integer number.

Comment: The next question would be "why `<< 0`"

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the left-shift [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) is being used to force the value into a 32-bit integer. From the MDN page I just linked:

> Shift operators convert their operands to 32-bit integers in big-endian order and return a result of the same type as the left operand.

Usually, numbers in JavaScript are double precision floats.